# Sprite in wrong direction

Tags: c#, xna

I use some code to calculate the path of a sprite. The front of the sprite texture is pointing upwards and that is the direction I want to move my sprite, but as it is now, the direction of the sprite is to the right of the sprite texture!? So when I rotate it a move in a new direction it's moves sideways. I hope my question isn't unclear? Help is preciated if there is a solution to change so the direction is pointing upwards of the sprite texture.

```
 public override void Update()
    {
        direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation));
        position += direction * speed;
    } 


public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
    }
```

Comment: Code looks right to me, it's probably your image which is facing the wrong direction. In your paint app, up == right.

Comment: Are your `Cos` and `Sin` calls the right way. What happens if you swap them in the `Vector2` constructor?

Comment: I guess the simpliest way is to change the texture so it facing right then, but it had looked better since it's a Asteroids game if the spaceship is facing up.

Comment: Vector2 constructor? I made a swap in the method, but didn't work!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix:

```
// Change it to +MathHelper.PiOver2 if it goes the wrong way
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation-MathHelper.PiOver2, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```

Just subtract (or add) 90 degrees from the rotation when you draw it

Comment: Interesting, but this just changed the sprite facing upwards, but it still mowes to the right!? Can you help me some more?

Comment: Change all the instances of `rotation` as shown in my example

Comment: Hmm, now I get it! Thanks! But I still wonder why -90 degrees not get straight up, but pointing up to the left? Isn't 0 degrees at right and then -90 up counter clockwise?

Comment: The rotation is in radians, so you probably haven't converted it. For 90 degrees I suggest you use `MathHelper.PiOver2`, as it takes less computations.

Comment: In computer graphics, 0 degrees is not straight up